Apple Push Notification - Customize message that is seen when the pass is changed
I am currently using nodejs but the answer can be in any language. Currently when I push a notification that an update on the card has been done the message appears as:
    const notification = new Notification(deviceToken, {
    "type": PushType.alert,
    
    priority: Priority.immediate,
    alert: {
      title: "Hello World",
      body: "Your first notification!", 
    },
    badge: 1,
    sound: 'default',
    topic: 'pass.ai.XXX.XXX', 
  });

organizationName
Pass changed

How can I customize the notification?

Do you want to print, Hello World in notiifcation banner  ?

@Shivbaba'sson Yes

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72391268/833395

@Shivbaba'sson Its not the same because thats to push for an app and rules are different for wallets.

https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn please check, actually i am not. a node.js guy, so do not know much
